How to handle redirect url in an electron project using Amplify federated sign in
I have setup an electron app using federated sign in and got it working successfully when running in a dev mode on localhost:1212. My code is complex but basically boils down to something like this
Auth.configure({
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: hubConfig.Region,
    userPoolId: hubConfig.Cognito.CognitoPool,
    identityPoolId: hubConfig.Cognito.CognitoIdentityPool,
    userPoolWebClientId: hubConfig.Cognito.CognitoClient,
    redirectSignIn: hubConfig.Cognito.RedirectSignIn,
    oauth: {
        domain: hubConfig.Cognito.HostedUI,
        redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:1212/login',
        redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:1212/login',
        responseType: 'code',
        scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
      },
  });

...

// set up the hub listener to listen for events.
  useEffect(() => {
    const hubListener = async (capsule: HubCapsule) => {
      const { payload } = capsule;
      console.log(
        `Received event: ${payload.event} with message ${payload.message}`
      );
      switch (payload.event) {
        case 'signIn': {
          const user = await Auth.currentSession();
          // Do some post sign in logic stuff
          break;
        }
        default:
          break;
      }
    };

    const unsubscribe = Hub.listen('auth', hubListener);

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };

...

await Auth.federatedSignIn({ customProvider: provider });


This just works. The problem with electron is once packaged it's url is file:///C:/ProgramData/.... rather than localhost and thats going to change depending on install location and OS.
What are you meant to do for a redirect URL to get this working in Electron?
I tried a url scheme myapp://login and can get that in my app and read the code url parameter from it but Amplify doesn't pick it up like it does when I use the apps URL. Have I missed something obvious?
